# Is C# Console.WriteLine(double) writing this variable with a full precision?

Tags: c#, precision

By "full precision" I mean that there won't be a case where the right result differs from the one I've calculated with my C# program.

I've checked this by running the same tests under a C# and C++ (without using cout.precision()). I'm sure the 2 variants of my program under C# and C++ act similarly on the same tests.

Sample code on C#.

```
double a;
//...code...
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

The same but on C++.

```
double a;
//...code...
cout << a << endl;
```

Actually my C++ program without cout.precision() failed and C# with nothing but Console.WriteLine() passed.

I know that this happens because my C++ program truncates the number somehow (maybe magically) and precision is lost. But does passing all the tests mean that C# always prints a doulbe variable with full precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you format your double with the "R" format specifier, you get a "round-trip" representation. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#RFormatString for details. Usage:

```
string s = someDoubleValue.ToString("R");
```

The default format specifier, if none is specified, is "G" (General), which "converts a number to the most compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation, depending on the type of the number and whether a precision specifier is present." See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#GFormatString for details. If no precision specificer is supplied, `double` gets 15 digits of precision, so using "G" offers the *possibility* of a loss of precision.

Comment: Thnx a lot. U have opened my eyes.

Comment: The linked page recommends not to use "R" for float or double, it says to use "G9" for Single and "G17" for double, though I suspect this changed after your answer was first posted.

Answer (score 3):

Both C++ and C# store floating point numbers as binary fractions. Not all numbers that have a 64-bit representation in base 2 have a reasonably-long representation in base 10. Some rounding will necessarily happen often when converting from a `double` to, say, a 15-digit decimal.

The reason you're seeing a difference is that the two languages make different default precision choices for converting base 2 to base 10 when printing. (Choices you can customize by printing with an output precision that will round off where you want it.)

Comment: Damn, that was what I was gonna say.

Comment: @millimoose, I know what u are saying but I use Console.WriteLine(0.333333333333333); shows 0.333333333333333 but cout << 0.333333333333333; shows 0.33333. Is it true that C# does not truncatate the floating values I give to it?

Comment: "Not all numbers that have a finite representation in base 2 have such a representation in base 10." That's not true, because 2 is one of 10's prime factors.  It *is* true that you might need dozens of significant digits to express the number exactly.

Comment: @novaco no, it's not true; the value might be truncated. See my answer, the documentation for the "G" format specifier, and Jon Skeet's linked article for more detail. Specifically, try your experiment with 0.3333333333333330 and 0.3333333333333334; the double values will be unequal, but their respective return values of ToString() will be equal.

Comment: @phoog It's true that any base 2 number can be represented in base 10, but not all finite base 10 numbers can be represented in a finite base 2 number (take the simple example of `0.1`).  When you take the base 10 number and assign it to the floating point number it is rounded, so when you ask for the base 10 number back it gives you the exact value of the already rounded number.  The underlying issue is still conversions between bases.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the correction, this might require a more significant rewrite of my answer.

Comment: @Servy, I am well aware that not all base 10 numbers can be represented in base 2; I did not intend to imply otherwise.  Of course, the compiler has to truncate or round decimal literals such as `0.1` when interpreting them as `double`, but given that C# numeric literals are typed, I was coming at the question from the assumption that `0.1d` in C# code denotes the binary representation rather than the mathematical quantity (1/10).

Comment: @millimoose +1 for identifying the key issue (different precision defaults)

Answer (score 1):

The exact decimal representation of a double value can go to dozens of places, so the answer in that respect is "no".  There is a round-trip format that guarantees enough precision to give a 1-to-1 correspondence between finite numeric decimal strings and finite numeric binary doubles (I don't know how it handles NaNs and infinities), but ToString doesn't use that format unless you specify it ("R"), so the answer in that respect is no, too.

In fact, if you use this overload, you get a result formatted according to the "G" format specifier (see [Double.ToString Method (IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045.aspx)).

For information about all the standard specifiers, see [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

Jon Skeet has a class that converts doubles to their (possibly very long) exact decimal representations; the associated article is here: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/FloatingPoint.aspx; the class itself is here: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/DoubleConverter.cs

Comment: "a 1-to-1 correspondence between finite numeric decimal strings and finite numeric binary doubles" - I'd phrase this a little differently. Maybe: "A 1-to-1 correspondence between all finite numeric binary doubles and their respective decimal string representations"

Comment: @millimoose good point; I didn't phrase it that way because I was thinking of "finite numeric decimal strings" as representing a subset of possible outputs of `double.Format()`, not as representing the set of all possible finite numeric decimal strings.